# how create pdf after image Draw c#

Tags: c#, pdf, webforms, pdfsharp

I'm working with PdfSharp to create some pdf files
I am trying to write an image after that save pdf and force download user
but after show box to download and open file, pdf was empty

```
var foo = new PrivateFontCollection();
    foo.AddFontFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/assets/css/base/fonts/Coustom.ttf"));
    var Font_6 = new Font((FontFamily)foo.Families[0], 6f);
    StringFormat rf = new StringFormat();
    rf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
    rf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;

    Brush _RedColor = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(63, 110, 123));
    System.Drawing.Image imgBackground = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("../assets/EmptyDoc/Letterhead-FA-A4.jpg"));

    int _X = 2300;
    int _Y = 450;

    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgBackground))
    {
        graphics.DrawString("TEST", Font_6, _RedColor, new PointF((_X - 40), (_Y)), rf);
    }
    imgBackground.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);



    byte[] fileContents = null;
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    document.Save(memoryStream, true);
    fileContents = memoryStream.ToArray();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;    filename=TEST.pdf");
    Response.BinaryWrite(fileContents);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PdfSharp, you can add an image as the following :

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(pngFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
   {
       XImage image = XImage.FromStream(stream);
       XGraphics graphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(this.currentPage);
       graphics.DrawImage(image, 0 , 0, 200, 100);
   }
```

you just need to replace pngFile by the full path of your drawing file.

Edit :

After reading your code, you could try to add this after the line `XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);` :

```
XImage image = XImage.FromStream(strm);
XGraphics graphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
graphics.DrawImage(image, 0 , 0, 200, 100);
```

Then replace

```
imgBackground.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

by

```
MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
imgBackground.Save(strm, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Seems the function doesn't accept your `Stream`, so try with a `MemoryStream`

Comment: my drawing file in on the fly , i dont have physical address

Comment: Thank you for your time.
I have a background photo, in the second step I insert a text on the background photo and save it in the temporary memory " imgBackground.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png)"
In the third step, after creating the image, I need to convert it to pdf without saving the image and download it as a force-download.

Comment: @amirlol I edited my answer, could you make that try?

Comment: I replaced your code as below
         XImage image = XImage.FromStream(Response.OutputStream);
         XGraphics graphic = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
         graphic.DrawImage(image,0,0,0,0);

and gives me the following error message

System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.

Comment: @amirlol on which line exactly? Then I see `DrawImage(image,0,0,0,0)` may be no correct (you set both width and height to 0), try like that `DrawImage(image,0,0,100,100)`

Comment: in this line : XImage image = XImage.FromStream(Response.OutputStream);

Comment: What is `Response.OutputStream`? I think the problem is because this is not a `System.IO.FileStream`?

Comment: When the following line is executed, the background image with text on it is created and displayed to the user

imgBackground.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249524/discussion-between-siegfried-v-and-amirlol).